# Is there a simple model that assumes a negative relationship between the mean and variance of response?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

Poisson and Negative Binomial models assume that the variance of response is greater or equal to the mean of response. Is there a simple model where that assumption is reversed, i.e. variance goes down as mean goes up.

Comment: You could simply negate a Poisson variable.

Comment: Does it have to be over integer values?

Comment: It doesn't have to be over integers, but it would be nice if it were non-negative.